# p:datatable how to manage a value equals to null

Tags: primefaces, datatable, null

I've created a datable giving the results of an API.

The problem is that this API return a list or a null.

When it's a null my page gives an error.

What can I do to fix it ?

Comment: Wrapping the API call in a method in a bean that returns an empty list if the API returns null???

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the API call in a method in a bean that returns an empty list if the API returns null.

```
public List<MyObject> getValues() {

    List<MyObject> apiResult = myService.getValues();
    if (apiResult == null) {
        apiResult = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return apiResult();
}
```